# trouble seeing axios.get parameters reactjs

Tags: reactjs, axios

I need to send http with parameters http://localhost:3000/pagination/?document=1110498198 but the setData does not load but I send it without parameters http://localhost:3000/pagination/  f it loads. !I need me to die in the setData all the path but with the parameters

```
const [data, setData]=useState([]);

const peticionGet =async() =>{
await axios.get("http://localhost:3000/paginacion/?documento=1110498198")
.then(response=>{
 setData(response.data);
}).catch(error=>{
  console.log(error);
}) }
```

Comment: Could you describe more about your question? Its not clear whats the problem!

Answer (score 0):

I need me to die in the setData all the path but with the parameters